# Aspose.Cells.CellsException - "You are using an evaluation copy and have opened files exceeding limitation"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I have created a function that returns a `datatable` from a `workbook`.

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableFromTabRowColumn(string sheetName, int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol)
  {
     var task = new Task(() =>
     {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Workbook wb = new Workbook(FilePath); // error line
        Worksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets[sheetName];

        dt = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(startRow - 1, startCol - 1, (endRow - startRow + 1), (endCol - startCol + 1), options);
     });

     task.Start();
     await task;

     return dt;
  }
```

It was running fine. When I made the function async, it's showing error:

> Aspose.Cells.CellsException: 'You are using an evaluation copy and
>   have opened files exceeding limitation.'

I am using licensed Aspose. Please help

Comment: The exception mentions clearly the problem , you're using trial version

Comment: No.. We are using licensed version

Comment: I have a hard time believing that this is your exact (real) code because this code tries to return **`dt`** from a scope where it does not exist.

Comment: It does sound a little like a fault in their license checking. But it's hard to be sure, like @peterB notes this is bad pseudo code. Contact the aspose helpdesk first and when you wan to ask here, post  2 minimal but _correct_ samples of working an not-working.

Comment: Ya.. That will be a issue. As I mentioned. I have just added the code within the task. The original one had only  4 lines (currently within the task) and returned dt. Since it's breaking before returning anything. I didn't figure out that issue

Comment: Well, This function was present in the application. My task was just to convert it to async which I have failed clearly. dt is initialized to null above all the functions.So there was no compile time error `private DataTable dt = null;`  Can you guide me the right way to implement async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the licence Aspose by [these methods](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/licensing)

> Aspose.Cells tries to find the license in the following locations:
>
> Explicit path The folder that contains Aspose.Cells.dll
>
> The folder that contains the assembly that called Aspose.Cells.dll
>
> The folderthat contains the entry assembly (your .exe)
>
> An embedded resource inthe assembly that called Aspose.Cells.dll

```
//Instantiate an instance of license and set the license file through its path
Aspose.Cells.License license = new Aspose.Cells.License();
license.SetLicense("Aspose.Cells.lic");
```

or

```
//Instantiate an instance of license and set the license through a stream
Aspose.Cells.License license = new Aspose.Cells.License();
license.SetLicense(myStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before blaming it on Aspose, lets fix the async approach.

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableFromTabRowColumn(string sheetName, int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol)
{                  
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {            
        Workbook wb = new Workbook(FilePath); // error line
        Worksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets[sheetName];

        DataTable dt = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(startRow - 1, startCol - 1, (endRow - startRow + 1), (endCol - startCol + 1), options);

        return dt;
    });

    return await task;            
}
```

Note that `dt` can and should be local like this.
Remove the `private DataTable dt = null;` line because it could cover up an error.

When this still gives an error I would look at Aspsose again.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have implemented it.  In aspose license file, there is a line <LicenseNote>Limited to 10 developers</LicenseNote>  May be the issue came because of that..

Comment: That would not explain the difference with non-async. Unless the async version is used to process more data in parallel.

Comment: I guess may be your licensing code is not processed at all, see the document on how to apply license for your reference: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/licensing Please make sure your licensing code is processed first and at least once in the whole application life cycle. PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.